# Composite key as foreign key from another table with comosite key as primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-key

Hi I want to create a database that has data about a hotel. The problem is that the relation with the order table and the room table. I want to see what rooms are available at a given time. I know there is something wrong with the relation on the table "order". Can I add a primary key as composite and at the same time connect them through composite foreign key that points to the table room?

When I try to run this code:

```
SELECT * FROM room LEFT JOIN order ON (room.hotelname=order.hotelname) AND (room.roomnr=order.roomnr)
```

The result is duplicate table. Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply!

```
CREATE TABLE hotel( 
hotelname varchar(50), 
location varchar(120), 
PRIMARY KEY (hotelname) 
); 

CREATE TABLE roomtype( 
roomtype varchar(50), 
PRIMARY KEY (roomtype) 
); 

CREATE TABLE hotelroomtype( 
hotellname varchar(50), 
roomtype varchar(50), 
NumberOfRoom int, 
PRIMARY KEY (hotelname, roomtype), 
CONSTRAINT FK_hotelname FOREIGN KEY (hotelname) REFERENCES hotel(hotelname), 
CONSTRAINT  FK_roomtype FOREIGN KEY (roomtype) REFERENCES roomtype(roomtype) 
); 

CREATE TABLE room( 
hotelname varchar(50), 
roomtype varchar (50), 
romnr int, 
PRIMARY KEY (hotelname, romnr), 
CONSTRAINT FK_hotelnameroomtype FOREIGN KEY (hotelname,roomtype) REFERENCES hotelroomtype(hotelname,roomtype) 
); 


CREATE TABLE user( 
username varchar(50), 
password varchar (50), 
userrole varchar(50), 
PRIMARY KEY (username) 
); 

CREATE TABLE order( 
hotelname VARCHAR (50), 
roomtype varchar (50), 
roomnr int, 
username varchar(50), 
dateArrival date, 
dateDeparture date, 
PRIMARY KEY (hotelname, roomnr); 
add CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (hotelname,roomnr) REFERENCES room(hotelname ,roomnr); 
add CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (roomtype) REFERENCES roomtype(roomtype); 
add CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES user(username); 
);

INSERT INTO hotell values("grand hotel oslo", "oslo"),("hotel klubben tønsberg", "Tønsberg"),("radisson blu gardermoen", "ullensarker"); 

INSERT INTO romtype VALUES ("enkeltrom"),("dobbeltrom"),("familierom"),("suite");

INSERT INTO hotellromtype VALUES ("grand hotel oslo", "enkeltrom", 50), ("grand hotel oslo", "dobbeltrom", 200), ("grand hotel oslo", "suite", 10), ("hotel klubben tønsberg", "enkeltrom", 10), ("hotel klubben tønsberg", "dobbeltrom", 150), ("hotel klubben tønsberg", "familierom",50);

INSERT INTO rom VALUES ("grand hotel oslo", "enkeltrom", 101),("grand hotel oslo", "enkeltrom", 102),("grand hotel oslo", "enkeltrom", 103),("grand hotel oslo", "dobbeltrom", 201),("grand hotel oslo", "dobbeltrom", 202),("grand hotel oslo", "dobbeltrom", 203);

INSERT INTO bruker values ("a", "a","admin" );


INSERT INTO bestilling values ('1','grand hotel oslo','enkeltrom' ,102,'a', '03-08-2019', '08-09-2019');
```

Comment: When you translate the names in the  `CREATE TABLE` statements (which is nice, that you posted them), then you should not forget to translate them in the query as well. And you should also post sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and your desired result with that data. Right now it's unclear what you want.

Comment: oh sorry! in short my task is to find available hotel rooms (for specified location / hotel and specified date / time period, any room type specified)